# How to replace the empty cell of excel using java

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to read the data from excel and want to create a Map in java for the header and value.

I'm able to read the data using java but I don't want to skip the empty values since I need to create a `hashmap` of the header and value even though it is empty.

```java
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    //For each row, iterate through all the columns
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext())
    {
         Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        //Check the cell type and format accordingly
        //System.out.println(cell.getCellType());

        if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
        {
            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ";");
        }
        if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
        {
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + ";");
        }
        if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) 
        {
            System.out.print("Blank");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
file.close();
```

```
attr_item_code;tag_warranty;MASTER;1032839;MASTER
```

I want to create a `hashmap` as below for the above data

```
{
  "attr_item_code":"1032839",
   "tag_warranty":"",
   "MASTER":"MASTER"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        boolean isHeader = true;
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> data = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        HashMap<Integer, String> headers = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int rowNum = 1;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    if (isHeader) {
                        data.put(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()), new ArrayList<String>());
                        headers.put(rowNum, String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                    } else {
                        ArrayList<String> tmp = data.get(headers.get(rowNum));
                        tmp.add(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                        data.put(headers.get(rowNum), tmp);
                    }
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ";");
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    if (isHeader) {
                        data.put(cell.getStringCellValue(), new ArrayList<String>());
                        headers.put(rowNum, cell.getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        ArrayList<String> tmp = data.get(headers.get(rowNum));
                        tmp.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        data.put(headers.get(rowNum), tmp);
                    }
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    if (isHeader) {
                        data.put("", new ArrayList<String>());
                        headers.put(rowNum, "");
                    } else {
                        ArrayList<String> tmp = data.get(headers.get(rowNum));
                        tmp.add("");
                        data.put(headers.get(rowNum), tmp);
                    }
                }
                rowNum++;
            }
            if (isHeader) {
                isHeader = false;
            }
        }
        file.close();
```

Comment: From the above code we are getting the exact headers but the data map is getting wrong values. you can add the below sysout and try printing the output

System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(data));
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(headers));
file.close();

Comment: The iterator is skipping the empty cells and moving forward and taking the forward cell data and placing into current header arraylist

Answer (score 0):

If you have empty rows in the column1 or column2, while (cellIterator.hasNext()) will skip empty cells. You will end up with no clue. So you have change the way of reading file.

You better read the excel file using the column index.

Sample code(Not compiled).

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    if (row != null) {

        // 1st cell
        Cell cell1 = row.getCell(1);

        // 2nd cell
        Cell cell2 = row.getCell(2);

        // 3rd cell
        Cell cell3 = row.getCell(3);
        ...... so on 

        // you know the cell type so read accordingly 

        // cell1.getNumericCellValue() or cell1.getStringCellValue() etc
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ReadExcelDemo1 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            String header="";
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Talend/Testing/master_old.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            boolean isHeader = true;

            //HashMap<String,Object> masterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            List<Object> masterList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> masterData = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
            HashMap<Integer, String> headers = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

            //int rowStart = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
            //int rowEnd = sheet.getLastRowNum();

            int rowStart = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
            int rowEnd = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            //System.out.println(sheet.getFirstRowNum() + " - ---------------"+sheet.getLastRowNum());

            for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum <= rowStart; rowNum++) 
            {
                Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                int lastColumn = r.getLastCellNum();
                for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) 
                {
                    Cell cell = r.getCell(cn);
                    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
                    {
                        int value = (int) Math.round(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        masterData.put(String.valueOf(value), new ArrayList<String>());
                        headers.put(cn, String.valueOf(value));
                    }
                    else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
                    {
                        masterData.put(String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue()), new ArrayList<String>());
                        headers.put(cn, String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                    }
                }
            }


            for (int rowNum = rowStart + 1; rowNum <= rowEnd; rowNum++) 
            {
                HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                if (r == null) 
                {
                    // This whole row is empty
                    // Handle it as needed
                    continue;
                 }
                int lastColumn = r.getLastCellNum();

                for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) 
                {
                   //Cell cell = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                   Cell cell = r.getCell(cn);
                   if(cell != null) 
                   {
                       if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
                       {
                          String headerValue = headers.get(cn);
                          List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
                          int value = (int) Math.round(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                          tmp.add(String.valueOf(value));
                          data.put(headerValue, tmp);

                       } 
                       else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
                       {
                           String headerValue = headers.get(cn);
                           List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
                           String strValue = String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
                           if(headerValue.startsWith("taxo_") || headerValue.startsWith("tag_") || headerValue.equals("MASTER"))
                           {
                               data.put(headerValue, Arrays.asList(strValue.split(",")));
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               tmp.add(String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                               data.put(headerValue, tmp);
                           }


                       } 
                       else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                       {
                           String headerValue = headers.get(cn);
                           List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
                           data.put(headerValue, tmp);  
                       }
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       String headerValue = headers.get(cn);
                       List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
                       data.put(headerValue, tmp);
                   }

                }
                masterList.add(data);

            }

            System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(masterList));
            //System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(headers));
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```